# jQuery Autocomplete not loading source from text

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, get

I'm having a problem getting a jQuery script to read a parts list I have in a text file as a source for my AutoComplete field. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var coffeeParts = $.get("coffeeParts.txt");
    $( "#partName" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: coffeeParts,
      select: function ( event, ui ) {
          $("#partNumber").text(ui.item.partNumber);
          $("#partDesc").text(ui.item.partDesc);
          if (ui.item.partSource == 1) {
              $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> Text to display</p></div></div>");
          }
          else if (ui.item.partSource == 2) {
              $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> Text to display</p></div></div>");
          }
          else {
              $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> Text to display</p></div></div>");
          }
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

The parts file is structured as so:

```
[{"label": "Part Name 1", "partNumber": "12345678", "partDesc": "Bla Bla Bla", "partSource": 1},{"label": "Part Name 2", "partNumber": "12345678", "partDesc": "Bla Bla Bla", "partSource": 1}]
```

When I run the page, entering text into my AutoComplete input box (`#partName`) doesn't bring up the list of possible choices. It doesn't seem to be placing the contents of coffeeParts.txt into the `coffeeParts` variable. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump the coffeeParts variable and call the file via the "source" parameter.   It already works like a .get() method.

```
$('#partName').autocomplete({
   minLength: 2,
   source: "coffeeParts.txt"
});
```

Comment: All of that driving myself crazy for such a simple fix. Thank you!

Comment: NP.  If at some point in the future you need to dynamically populate an autocomplete field from a database, you can find an example of that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686968/how-to-save-a-value-to-an-sql-databse-using-an-onfocus-function-via-ajax/)

Comment: What if, for instance, I want to use an AJAX call and JQuery CSV as my source? That's sort of my interim step between a fully dynamic source and the static source above. I've tried using the solution suggested here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229403/why-are-jquery-autocomplete-results-not-showing-in-browser), but nothing populates the autocomplete field.

Comment: You'll want to create a php file that converts that csv into a JSON string for use in autocomplete, then call that php file via source.  Just remember to echo the JSON string at the end of the file so that autocomplete can read it.